# Choose max out of calculated expression. QLIK SENSE

Tags: max, qlikview, qliksense

When I use Qlik, How can I choose only the max result out of this expression?
My dimension is "MachineNumber":

```
sum(If(Machine <> 'STOPS', DowntimeDuration))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
max(aggr(sum({$<Machine-={'STOPS'}>} DowntimeDuration), MachineNumber))
```

The above uses set analysis to select only the running machines, then creates a virtual table of durations by machine number. The maximum value in the virtual table is then selected. Keep in mind that the `$` set identifier will also grab any other active selections in the default state.

Comment: This looks perfect, but for some reason it ain't working. I'll do more research with your answer. Thanks!